# Десятичные с точкой в десятичное

Tags: shell

Как можно преобразовать ip из dec 3232235777 в dec с точкой 192.168.1.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно 3232235777 перевести в щестнадцатиричную систему(hex), потом по байтам назад в десятичную(dec), вот примерно пошаговый процесс

```
dec 3232235777 = hex 0xC0A80101 
hex 0xC0A80101 = hex C0.A8.01.01
hex C0.A8.01.01 = dec 192.168.1.1
```

Comment: Только про преобразование из формата хоста в формат сети (C функция htonl()) не забывайте.

Comment: ок спс разобрался!!

Comment: Так оно уже в формате хоста

Answer (score 7):

Вдогонку.

```
function i2d() {
    a=$1
    for((i=0;$i<4;i++))
    do 
        ar[$i]=$((a%256))
        a=$(($a/256))
    done
    echo ${ar[3]}.${ar[2]}.${ar[1]}.${ar[0]}
}
i2d 3232235777
192.168.1.1
```

Comment: мисье знает толк в извращениях.

Comment: очень даже удобно!

Comment: А shell - это вообще наука извращения )))